# Implicit resolution does not work with Scala 3 anymore (Pure Config)

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, dotty, scala-3

In my Scala 3 project I want to use Pure Config. But I get the following exception:

```
[error] -- Error: /Users/mpa/dev/Github/experiments/dotty-cross/src/main/scala/pme123/camunda/dmn/tester/TestConfigHandler.scala:20:22 
[error] 20 |  ConfigReader[String].map(_.getBytes.toVector)
[error]    |                      ^
[error]    |Cannot find an implicit instance of pureconfig.ConfigReader[String].
[error]    |If you are trying to read or write a case class or sealed trait consider using PureConfig's auto derivation by adding `import pureconfig.generic.auto._`.
[error]    |I found:
[error]    |
[error]    |    pureconfig.Derivation.materializeDerivation[A]
[error]    |
[error]    |But method materializeDerivation in object Derivation does not match type pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[String]].
```

I just took the simple example from the doc:

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

case class BytesConf(bytes: Vector[Byte])

// reads an array of bytes from a string
implicit val byteVectorReader: ConfigReader[Vector[Byte]] =
  ConfigReader[String].map(_.getBytes.toVector)
}
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    ..,
    scalaVersion := dottyVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ...
      "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.14.0"
    ).map(_.withDottyCompat("2.13.3")) :+
      ("com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11"),
    ..
  )
```

Do I miss something or is this not possible at the moment?

Comment: This is the 2.13 library you're using, right? Auto derivation is probably done with macros, and 2.13 macros don't work in scala 3.

Comment: @Jasper-M thanks I was thinking this could be the problem.